# How to select record with latest time date stamp

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I just cant figure this out.  I have a table that is the following:

routeLogTbl

```
id          pro     trailer     arrival_date    arrival_time
-------     ------- ---------   ------------    ------------
1           55      691995      2018-04-04      23:50:00    
2           59      691995      2018-03-15      23:22:00    
3           47      691995      2018-04-02      23:23:00    
4           66      691995      2018-04-05      07:00:00    
5           577     691995      2018-04-02      23:50:00
```

What I want is the latest record id by concantenating the date and time. I know I have to use max but it is weird.  If I run the following query I DO get the max date but I don't get the anticipated record id that matched the MAX.

```
SELECT
   routeLogTbl.pro,
   MAX( TIMESTAMP( routeLogTbl.arrival_date, routeLogTbl.arrival_time ) ) AS DelTimeDate 
FROM
   routeLogTbl 
WHERE
   routeLogTbl.trailer = 691995 
GROUP BY
   routeLogTbl.trailer
```

Comment: _I don't get the anticipated record id that matched the MAX_. Well what DO you get?

Comment: Sorry, I always get the first record (lowest id) but the correct one is pro 66

Comment: Hey! You edited your question to change your data! That cleared up your problem about getting the wrong row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a subquery to get the extreme value of the date/time, then using join criteria to retrieve the detail record, is the standard way of doing this. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d588b/1/0)

```
SELECT detail.*
  FROM tbl detail
  JOIN ( 
         SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP( arrival_date, arrival_time)) arrival_datetime,
                trailer
           FROM tbl
          GROUP BY trailer
       ) m   ON detail.trailer=m.trailer
            AND TIMESTAMP( arrival_date, arrival_time) = arrival_datetime
```

This will give one row in your result set for each distinct value of `trailer`.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to sort and only get one:

```
SELECT
   routeLogTbl.pro,
   TIMESTAMP(routeLogTbl.arrival_date, routeLogTbl.arrival_time) AS DelTimeDate
FROM
   routeLogTbl 
WHERE
   routeLogTbl.trailer = 691995 
ORDER BY
   routeLogTbl.arrival_date DESC,
   routeLogTbl.arrival_time DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Sorry I was trying to not make this complicated but I will be passing a bunch of trailers to in with a NOT IN statement to load the query with a list of trailers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it, with a subquery for getting the max timestamp:

```
SELECT  route.pro,
        TIMESTAMP(route.arrival_date, route.arrival_time) DelTimeDate 
FROM    routeLogTbl route
WHERE   trailer = 691995
AND     TIMESTAMP(arrival_date, arrival_time) = (
    SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP(effdt.arrival_date, effdt.arrival_time)) FROM routeLogTbl effdt WHERE effdt.trailer = route.trailer
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a SQLFiddle for you: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b8817f/9/0

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM routeLogTbl
WHERE TIMESTAMP(arrival_date, arrival_time) = 
(SELECT MAX(TIMESTAMP(arrival_date, arrival_time)) FROM routeLogTbl);
```

Without `JOIN`s.

Results:

```
id  pro     trailer     arrival_date    arrival_time
4   66  691995  2018-04-05  07:00:00
```